# Laplace method when all derivatives at the critical point are 0

Tags: integration, analysis, laplace-method

When trying to estimate by the Laplace method the simple integral $ \int_0^1 e^{-n f(x)}dx $ with $ f(x) := \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1 - x} - 4 $, I ended up realising that all the derivatives at the extrema $ x^* = 1/2 $ are in fact equal to $0$. The true case I am considering being more complicated (in higher dimension), I was wondering : what happens if all the higher order derivatives taken at the critical point are $0$ ? Is there a standard reference for such a problem ?

Comment: You need some canonical function that agrees with $f(x)$ near the critical point and quickly goes to $-\infty$ far away from the critical point. What this function looks like depends on how the integrand really behaves.

Comment: Is there any recipe to construct such a "canonical" function ? For the simple function $f$ that I gave, is it already simple ?

Comment: Actually in your "toy" case there is no problem, the even derivatives do not vanish.

Comment: Ooops. Indeed, I was tired/asleep when I computed it :) and made a sign mistake. But the question remains : is there a reference in general. I can write (in another question) the case I am considering (it is on a space of matrices).

Comment: In general, if your function is _analytic_ (as your example is, being composed of rational functions...), it cannot have all derivatives vanishing at a point (unless it's identically $0$). Beginning with the idea of $e^{1/|x|}$ one can construct functions of the sort you desire.

Comment: My previous point is still there. The even derivatives do not vanish. You just fixed the convergence.

Comment: @Ian : yes, I know, I just didn't like this non converging integral...

Comment: @paulgarrett : Indeed. There is the famous example of Cauchy to construct a function whose derivatives all vanish at one point, but this is not my $f$. This proves that I had the wrong intuition on my multi-dimensional case (which is also rational, in some sense). My problem is more that I have a Hessian which is not invertible (and it continues, etc.). I will write a new question with the good case this time, since finding a simple equivalent in dimension 1 is not accurate.

Comment: My new question is here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576663/multidimensional-integral-with-the-laplace-method